# hide div using javascript even though documents gets reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually, I am working with ajax to display the dynamic elements.
I am setting up a a div on a button click using **javascript**, this div contains form elements, after this form gets submitted i need to hide this div, so that it's no longer seen on *UI*.

The problem I am facing  is, once I hide the div, its working fine, but when I reload the page the div is occurring again.

The wanted to make the div hidden permanently once I click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the state of the `div` being hidden inside of `localStorage`.

Example:

```js
const divHidden = localStorage.getItem('divHidden') === 'yes';

// if (!divHidden) show div

// Then when the div is being hidden:

localStorage.setItem('divHidden', 'yes');
```

You can also listen for the `storage` event on `window` to update any other tabs of your web application:

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('divHidden') === 'yes') {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Mat Sz, but this making my div hidden for all pages, where i don't want to hide it. For example. if my div is hidden on the display page, then it hiding the same div onto my index page also, as i am using the div on multiple pages.

Comment: See project requirements are like this, their multiple company cards, in each individual card there is this div, to take the inputs, after taking the inputs, i need to hide this div and show the processed data based on the inputs. As u suggested me to do, i did, but its disabling my all div's of other cards too.

Comment: Use other IDs and keys for other divs. That should solve it.